# Why can't we send a UDP packet from an Android emulator?

Tags: android, networking, udp, android-emulator, packet

My friend and I have a wireless robot dog connected to a wifi network
which our computer is plugged into. The computer is running an
Android emulator and we are trying to send a UDP packet to the
wireless robot dog. If the dog receives it, it should start sending
UDP packets back. The program we wrote works outside of the emulator,
and using Wireshark, we see that the packet is sent to the correct IP
address and the correct MAC address for the robot. When we attempt to
send the packet from the emulator, the dog does not respond how it
should if it received the packet. In Wireshark we can see that the
emulator sends the packet to the correct IP address for the dog, but
not the correct MAC address. It is sending it to the MAC address of
the router we are plugged into. We want to specify the packet so that
it sends to the correct MAC address but we cannot figure out how to do
this. Any help would be great

Comment: Which platform are you developing on? I'm wondering if it might be an OS-specific quirk that the emulator has fallen prey to!

Comment: Windows XP.  we got it working, although we never figured out why we were having this problem, once it started working, we haven't had the problem since

Comment: What did you do to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Old question... but this is probably what you're looking for.. it describes your symptoms.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d6856a3f412e06b8